# font-weight lighter is not a font-weight value

Tags: css

I'm getting a Validator error for my stylesheets but I don't know how to solve that one.
The error:

```
Value Error : font-weight lighter is not a font-weight value : lighter
```

And the CSS causing the error:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('../fonts/OpenSans-Light-webfont.svg#opensans') format('svg');
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Isn't "lighter" a standard value? Or do I have to use "font-weight:100" instead? I'm confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the `lighter` weight relates to the weight value of the parent element. In the case of `@font-face` there is no parent element, and therefore a lighter font-weight cannot be determined.

So yes, you'll have to use `font-weight: 100;` if that's your desired weight.

It's worth noting that `100` isn't equal to `lighter`. The value of `lighter` depends on the parent value. If the parent value is `900`, for instance, `lighter` will set the value to `700` ([as noted in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#lighter)).

Comment: Values do not inherit values, and setting a property to a value *prevents* inheritance. You are probably trying to say that the value is relative to the value for the parent element.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't "lighter" a standard value?

Not within an `@font-face` rule, there isn't anything for it to be lighter relative to, see [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#descdef-font-weight).

> Or do I have to use "font-weight:100" instead?

Yes

Comment: Open Sans does not have weight 100. The smallest weight for it is 300, and the name Open Sans Light is conventionally use for that typeface. So apparently `font-weight: 300` should be used.